# How to format result data for FullCalendar eventSources URL

Tags: php, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to call my events for fullcalendar from a sepeate URL.
I am using this method here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
    '/feed1.php'
  ]
});
```

How do I format the results in "**/feed1.php**" ?

I have tried the typical JSON format that usually works:

```
{ID:'1265',start:'2018-11-15',title:'Bentley', editable : false, allDay : true},
{ID:'1222',start:'2018-11-14',title:'Dave', editable : false, allDay : true}
```

But this is not working.

Is there a format I should be using for the dates I want to show up from "**/feed1.php**" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid - and also wrong in other respects relating to what fullCalendar expects. You probably have errors in your browser console, if you check.

- Your JSON should be constructed an an array with `[` and `]` at the
  start and end of the string respectively.
- In JSON you must use double-quotes (`"`) around the property names
  and values (instead of single quotes (`'`). 
  Also *all* property names must have quotes round them.
- Finally, fullCalendar expects `ID` should be `id`.

I don't know how you're constructing your results, but you should really be making an array of event objects in PHP and then using `json_encode()` to let PHP turn that array into valid JSON.

Here's an example using some static PHP data, although I assume in reality you'll construct your array from database data or something.

```
<?php
$events = array(
    array("id" => 1265, "start" => "2018-11-15", "title" => "Bentley", "editable" => false, "allDay" => true),
    array("id" => 1222, "start" => "2018-11-14", "title" => "Dave", "editable" => false, "allDay" => true),
);
echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

This will output valid JSON as follows:

```
[{
    "id": 1265,
    "start": "2018-11-15",
    "title": "Bentley",
    "editable": false,
    "allDay": true
},
{
    "id": 1222,
    "start": "2018-11-14",
    "title": "Dave",
    "editable": false,
    "allDay": true
}]
```

Here's a [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8da4b5fb68333c73851a04eef7fce18f4bcf20e7) of that code.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/13/) of fullCalendar using that JSON output to display the events correctly.

Here is the [json_encode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Additionally, fullCalendar also [documents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) the field names it expects each event to have.